# Unable to initialize firebase in correct directory

Tags: angular, firebase, npm

I'm trying to deploy my angular 2 project to firebase. I succeeded the first time but after that, even though the project is deployed to firebase, it's not showing up in the url.(It's just showing firebase hosting's welcome page) 
I also noticed that even though I have navigated to the dist folder(created after ng build operation) the firebase init is still running in parent directory, which may be causing the problem. How to solve this?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\BEN> e:
PS E:\> cd project\angular-proj
PS E:\project\angular-proj>
PS E:\project\angular-proj> cd dist
PS E:\project\angular-proj\dist> firebase init

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  E:\project\angular-proj        

Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

? Are you ready to proceed? (Y/n) n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the source of the problem. I had typed 'ng build -prod' instead of 'ng build --prod' while building the application. Now the problem is solved.